# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "opening archive failed"?

Tags: traducción, informática

Estoy traduciendo un software y en él me encuentro con frases del tipo:

> **Opening archive failed** with error code 500

La frase en sí es un poco chusquera y me cuesta ver por dónde cogerla.
Mi primer pensamiento ha sido traducirla como:

> **La apertura del fichero ha fallado** con un código de error 500

Sin embargo, este "*la apertura*" me suena bastante mal y estoy  tentado a hacer una traducción libre del tipo:

> **El fichero no ha podido abrirse** y ha devuelto el error de código 500

¿Cómo conecto *opening* con la devolución del código de error? ¿Cómo traduzco el nombre *opening* como acción?

Comment: I am not sure how relevant this is but I would take archive to be a specific sort of file whereas I thought, perhaps wrongly, that fichero was any sort of file.

Comment: Aunque tu primer intento te suena mal, a mi me suena perfecto con solo una observación. Si tu traducción va a ser usada en España, "fichero" está perfecto, pero en latinoamérica no. Por ejemplo en Colombia les decimos "archivos". Fichero se entiende pero no se usa.

Comment: Sí, pasa lo mismo en Chile, se usa *archivo*.

Comment: Tengo mis dudas sobre el uso de _fichero_ en España para _archive_. Puede ser sólo una concepción errada del campo semántico de _fichero_, pero me parece que _archive_ estuviera queriendo significar algo más que sólo _file_.

Comment: Ya se que llego muy tarde, pero _archive_ hasta dónde yo se es siempre un archivo que contiene otros archivos dentro, específicamente. Es decir, un .rar, .zip o .tar son _archives_, un .txt o .jpg no lo son. Un .gz sería _compressed file_, y un .tar.gz un _archive_. Pero no se de ninguna palabra en castellano que cumpla la misma función. Y en este caso no parecería muy relevante distinguirlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una traducción (casi palabra a palabra), pero que evita la palabra *apertura*, y sigue siendo lo suficientemente neutral y fluida podría ser:

> **Falló el intento de abrir del archivo**[fichero] con código de error 500

Otra posibilidad, un poco más libre, y un poco más natural para mi gusto (pero en esto los regionalismos a veces influyen más de lo que uno se imagina), podría ser:

> **Error al abrir el archivo**. Código de error: 500

En todo caso, no soy muy amigo de dar códigos de error sin más, pero esa es una decisión de diseño de los programadores originales en la que quizás no se pueda influir. Pudiendo, prefiero dar posibles explicaciones, o al menos poner un *link* desde el código de error a la ayuda: ¿de qué le sirve a un usuario promedio el código 500? Eso se justificaba más en los 80.

Comment: Para mi gusto la repetición de la palabra error se justifica porque en la segunda oración es un modificador necesario para _código_. Si se quiere, también se podría omitir diciendo `Código: 500`, pero temo que puede empezar a quedar demasiado telegráfico.

Comment: Me gusta la segunda opción. Yo incluso diría _ha ocurrido un error al abrir el archivo_ o, si andas bien de espacio, _ha ocurrido un error al intentar abrir el archivo_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Entiendo que en España usan más el pretérito perfecto y el verbo _ocurrir_. Dicho en Chile a me suena muy formal (hasta un poco anticuado o sobrecorregido)

Comment: Curioso, a mí me suena normal. La alternativa que se me ocurre es _ha sucedido un error_, pero esa no me suena del todo natural. Es muy interesante conocer esta diversidad en las formas de expresarse en el español de los distintos países.

Comment: El tiempo _ha ocurrido_ lo usamos aquí para cosas sucedidas en un pasado muy reciente, y _ocurrió_ sería para hechos más alejados en el tiempo. Lo mismo sirve para cualquier otro verbo.

Comment: Sí, me gusta la sugerencia de @CarlosAlejo de _ha ocurrido_. Y, efectivamente, el espacio es un factor importante, sobre todo cuando se traduce del inglés y, por ende, la diferencia de número de caracteres es tan notable.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo traduciría como

> En abriendo(se) el archivo se produjo un error con/de código 400

Evitaría *al abrir(se)* porque el error, se supone, se produce dentro de la apertura y no justo después que implica *al*. También se puede decir *en abrir(se)*, ya que *en* admite tanto gerundio como infinitivo sin distinción.

Comment: Interesante, me gusta lo que sugieres. Lo que me suena muy raro es el "en" que pones al principio. Me suena mucho mejor "Abriendo el archivo...".

Comment: @fedorqui A los gerundios introducidos por *en* se los llama *gerundios preposicionales*. No son incorrectos, pero no se usan con frecuencia salvo en algunas variedades de español o cuando se quiere dar un aire "antiguo" a un texto. Desde luego, no para un mensaje de un software, en mi opinión.

Comment: @Yay caramba, gracias por la explicación. No conocía el concepto. Al oído suena propio de un contexto jurídico, de ahí que tampoco a mí me encaje como mensaje para un usuario de software. Encontré [un artículo la mar de interesante](http://desequilibros.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/en-gerundio-usos.html) que muestra su evolución desde su origen para significar simultaneidad hasta la anterioridad inmediata.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí que es curioso. Yo siempre pensé que era un calco del francés, pero parece que no.

Comment: @fedorqui y Yay, pilado jaja, soy medievalista y asturfalante, así que ya veis.  A veces a uno se le olvida de que lo que le es normal no se lo es para todos.

Answer (score 1):

*opening* podría verse como un participio presente, en ese caso podría armar una cláusula de este estilo:

> *El archivo **que se está abriendo** falló con código de error 500.*

Por supuesto que se pueden añadir otras cosas como artículos y reemplazar *falló* para adecuarlo a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like the first or:

> El archivo/fichero no se pudo abrir.  Código de error 500

Or

> Abrir el archivo ha fallado con...